# Is the calculation of variance correct from an estimator -- confusion regarding complex number where I am going wrong?

Tags: matlab, complex, parameter-estimation

I have an expression for the varaince of measurement noise obtained from an estimator. The measurement noise is additive white gaussian having values in complex domain. I have squared the term $(.)^2$, should I be squaring or just implement without squaring? But if I dont square the term, then I am getting a complex valued variance which is incorrect as variance is always real valued.

Kindly suggest what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put:

$$\sigma^2=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^N(y_i-\hat{y}_i)\overline{(y_i-\hat{y}_i)}$$

that is, replacing your code by:

```
for i = 1: N
   dy(i,1) = (y(i)-yhat(i))*conj(y(i)-yhat(i));
end
sigma2 = 1/(N-1)*sum(dy);
```

The [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) is the ***[second moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)#Central_moments_in_metric_spaces)*** of a probability distribution, which can be defined for any [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) in the sense of the definition over the random variable (integral of a density), or in any vector space, in the sense of the estimator of the random variable (sum of n samples).

For $X$ a random variable  $\in \mathbb{R}^n$, with probability density function $p(x):I_X \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the second moment $\in \mathbb{R}$ is:

$$\sigma^2=\mathbf{E}\{(X-\mu)^2\}=\int_{I_X} (x-\mu)^2 p(x)dx$$

which is the *variance* for $n=1$ and the *covariance matrix* in general.

For other fields $\mathbb{F}$, complex and even real numbers, the metric $d(x,y): \mathbb{F}x\mathbb{F}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can redefine the moment definition

$$\sigma^2_{\mathbb{F}}=\mathbf{E}_{\mathbb{F}}\{(X-\mu)^2\}=\int_{I_X} d(x,\mu)^2 p(x)dx$$

For example, for the complex field, the metric function can be the standard distance from the [hermitian inner product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html), and thus we have the [variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632831/variance-of-a-sum-of-complex-independent-random-variables) definition:

$$d(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-y)\overline{(x-y)}}$$
$$\sigma^2_{\mathbb{C}}=\mathbf{E}_{\mathbb{C}}\{(X-\mu)^2\}=\int_{I_X} (x-y)\overline{(x-y)} p(x)dx$$

But the standard product, without the conjugated term, though can be a valuable figure (named as the "[complementary variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_random_variable)") is **not** a second moment:

$${\sigma^2}_{\mathbb{C}comp}=\int_{I_X} (x-y)^2 p(x)dx$$

Of course, you always could be more "reasonable" and prefer to drop the complex analysis and move onto a $\mathbb{C}^2$ cartesian plane, and start taking covariances instead of a single number which dont dive you the full distribution information of your stochastics.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have taken the complex conjugate of the second term if you may kindly see the code in my question. Moreover, there is a multiplication term with $y$ in the expression $(y(y-yhat))$. I took the conjugate for that term and I think you have not mentioned this part which is how to handle multiplication with iteself for scalar complex valued number. What I have done is the same as your answer except for the doubt in the term $y_n \times y_n$. I plugged you code and still I am getting very large value for the variance like 2 to three digit number.

Comment: I checked your code and you are calculating a different expression which dont make any known symmetry to me. You should take `A=y(i)` and `B=yhat(i)`. The square root of the result should preserve the dimensional symmetry. Could you plot the point cloud in the z plane and the variance result you are having?

Comment: Besides, you can made two different calculations with `A1=real(y(i))` `B1=real(yhat(i))` and for `A2=imag(y(i))` `B2=imag(yhat(i))`. `sigma1` and `sigma2` should trivially preserve the dimensionality......

Comment: Regarding your comment, the complex product is handled as ussualy defined in the $\mathbb{C}$ field, and there are no `y(i)*y(i)` terms, only `y(i)*conj(y(i))`.Do you remember the bracket notation? $<a|b>=a\overline{b}$

Comment: Could you please clarify (1) Whenever I have Multiplication with same complex numbers, should I be taking the conjugate of the other term? (2) same for multiplication with different complex number? So whenever we have multiplication, it would be complex multiplication? The tutorial https://www2.clarku.edu/~djoyce/complex/mult.html here says differently. I am now very confused. Lastly, (3) The equation of the variance has a  $y$ term on the outside based on the derivation, and so would `dy1(i,1) = y(i)*conj(y(i)); dy2(i,1) = y(i)*yhat(i); dy3(1,i) = (dy1(i,1)-dy2(i,1))*conj(dy1(i,1)-dy2(i,1));`

Comment: I have asked a part 2 question based on this one and I was hoping if you may kindly have a look at the question as a favor to help me. The new question is in more detail but basically I am asking if I need to implement this equation based on a state space approach or not. The link to the question is  http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36045/conceptual-question-on-how-to-calculate-implement-the-log-likelihood-equation-a

Comment: I had asked a question  regarding complex multiplication http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045318/multiplication-in-complex-domain?noredirect=1#comment4198499_2045318 and it seems that multiplication using two complex numbers does not involve conjugating the other number. So, why should I do `y(i)*conj(y(i))` is not clear

Comment: Ive just checked your questions.... I will address them and kill your doubts one by one.... :)

Comment: Thank you for going through the question but unfortunately, my understanding is still not clear regarding why we should the expression $y_n(y_n - \hat{h z})$ be evaluated as `A = y(n)*conj(y(n))` and   `B = y(n)*\mathbf{h z}`. If we are conjugating here `y(n)*conj(y(n))` then why not conjugate for the other terms  `y(n)*\mathbf{h z}`?Basically  I am squaring `y(n)`, so it should be simple complex number multiplication and not norm. Only in norm we take the conjugate ${||A-B||}^2$

Comment: The expression $y_n(y_n-hz)$ has no clear sense to me........ That is not a variance.....

Comment: I will recheck the derivation of the variance, but in general if there is an expression like this involving multiplication `result = a(a - cd) ` where the numbers `a,b,c` are complex valued, then should I be doing `result = a*conj(a) - a*c*d` ?

Comment: Forget the complex numbers, buddy.... That is not correct... You have to follow the formulation, not change it. Dont add those conjugations that way....